# Comment section for documents in document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I want to have comment functionality for each document in document library, just like the same way we have it in sitepage for Modern UI. 
Is it possible to achieve it ? 
Thanks in Advance!!!
Ujwal N
[Click for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXf8w.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

not available out of the box. You would need to create custom functionality/page  for this.